# How can a top level directory structure reveal the purpose of the application?

Tags: c#, mvvm, architecture

Robert C. Martin in one of his talks about clean architecture openly criticizes fairly standard way of doing things nowadays.
[Robert C. Martin - Clean Architecture and Design](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=asLUTiJJqdE#t=757s)

What I understand as `standard way` is something like this:

```
solution
    - UI project
        - Models
        - Views
        - Controllers
        - Assets
    - Logic project
    - Data project
```

Martin here says, that the application should reveal its purpose immediately when you look at its top level directory structure... I wonder, can anyone provide an example of such directory structure, for instance while using MVVM pattern as a delivery mechanism? How can one structure his application the way Martin is describing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in your example I can only guess that it is a ASP.NET MVC application, we need to take a look at the `Logic` or `Data` projects to understand what this application is about.

Most of the time people organize all their directory structure based on the technology or framework used.  This comes from the way default project template are created (knowing nothing about what your application is supposed to do they really can't do much more than that for us).

Now, what Robert C. Martin tells us is that our top level directory structure should reflect on what the application does and not how it is built.  I'm not sure it is a good idea to do that at the solution level.  However, I always recommend to have a `Domain` project were we could apply [Domain Driver Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) principles.

If in such *Domain* project you see at the root level the following folders:

```
Clients
Orders
Billing
Shipping
Promotions
...
```

You could guess it is some kind of E-commerce application.  You would have to go even deeper in the directory structure if the folders you would have found are like `Models`, `DTOs` or `Exceptions`.

I don't like to have too many projects in my solution (under 10 if possible) so I don't go and create one project per domain object of my system.  This is why I think the root level of projects not solutions are were we should focus our attention on defining what the application is doing.

Comment: Yes, this is a kind of an answer I was hoping for. Thank you, definitely +1.

Answer (score 0):

He isn't talking about a structure that gives away the application purpose as such. He said, at the top level there should be use cases so you can quickly see what it does and where code changes are required. I dont think he was talking about folder names at all. More information availbility.

Comment: `Open up the top level and there's there all the use cases there, and then you say 'oh but I need to change one of those use cases, which one, aaah, this one here, because it's named'. How do you have to change code now? You got to figure out which url activates which particular controller and then you got to dig in controller and...`. I understand that he talks about a good architecture as a whole, but he stresses the importance of a good folder structure as well. I just want to see an example of an application structured like that, that hides its delivery mechanism and exposes it's purpose.